# Scope for nested resources using pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, pundit

I have the following relations:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :analyses, dependent: :destroy
end

class Analysis < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

To use scopes in Patient is simple, I just did:

```
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        scope.where(user_id: user.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

But how can I use do it to get all the analysis that only belongs to one specific patient using the resolve method?

Right now my analysis_policy look like this:

```
class AnalysisPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def new?
    true
  end

  def edit?
    record.patient.user_id == user.id
  end

  alias_method :show?, :edit?
  alias_method :create?, :edit?
  alias_method :destroy?, :edit?
end
```

And the index action in AnalysesController:

```
  def index
    @analyses = @patient.analyses
  end

  ...
  private

  def set_patient
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`Analysis.joins(:patient).where(patient: { user_id: user.id })` should work.  It might be `where(patients: { user_id: user.id })` I can't remember. So as a scope on Analysis it'd be

```
class Analysis < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  scope :for_user ->(user_id) { joins(:patient).where(patient: { user_id: user_id })
end
```

So then you'd use `Analysis.for_user(user.id)`